# Check email validity with FluentValidation when property is not empty

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, fluentvalidation

I'd like with FluentValidation check the email format. The email is not mandatory. Then I have to check only when the property is not empty.How can I do this ? Below I check all the time.

```
RuleFor(x => x.Email)
    .EmailAddress()
    .WithLocalizedMessage(() => "My message.");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [where or unless](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/conditions.html).

```
RuleFor(x => x.Email)
    .EmailAddress()
    .WithLocalizedMessage(() => "My message.")
    .Unless(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Email));
```

EDIT: Updated documentation link.

Comment: The updated doc is here: https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/conditions.html

Comment: @Dejan updated documentation link. Thanks, hvala ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use When to handle that

```
RuleFor(x => x.Email)
.EmailAddress()
.When(e =>e.Email !=String.Empty)
.WithLocalizedMessage(() => "My message.");
```